# How can I echo something only if the woo-commerce product id is listed in my array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to echo a script only if the WP product id is listed in the array. The below code is of course working only for the first product id (226), but I am not sure how to update this part `if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 226)` in order to check among all of the array elements

```
$booking = array(
    '226' => 349992,
    '2456' => 349999,
    '2498' => 350001,
    '2500' => 350002,
    '2502' => 350003,
    '2504' => 350006,
    '2665' => 350008
);
            $item_number = $booking[$product->get_id()];
$fh_cal = '<script src="https://test.com/embeds/script/calendar-small/test/items/'.$item_number.'/?fallback=simple&full-items=no"></script>';
            if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 226) {
    echo $fh_cal;
} else {
include ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/test/inc/form.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the product exists in that array, we can simply do an `isset()` to check it:

Change

```
&& get_the_id() == 226
```

to

```
&& isset($booking[get_the_id()])
```

That will evaluate as `true` if there is an array element with that ID as key